# How can I convert a column of Excel into a specific dictionary format?

Tags: python, dictionary, openpyxl

I have one column in my excel file, i want to convert all the rows of the column into a specific  dictionary format. 
that is, the keys and values between double quotation and values between brackets and parentheses and before that, the word is set, as seen in the picture:[image]

I use this code but This does not give me the format I want:

```
import openpyxl

# Access active worksheet of excel file
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
sheet = book.active

# Access first column
column = sheet['A']

# Use dictionary comprehension on the cells in the column
d = {
    'item{}'.format(num): cell.value
    for (num, cell) in enumerate(column, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image shows the values in the dictionary as single value [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), rather than integers. You can put the `cell.value` into a set:

```
d = {
    'item{}'.format(num): {cell.value} for (num, cell) in enumerate(column, 1)
}
```

To check:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'item1': {5},
 'item2': {2},
 'item3': {0},
 'item4': {1},
 'item5': {6},
 'item6': {6},
 'item7': {1}}
>>> pprint([type(d[key]) for key in d.keys()])
[<class 'set'>,
 <class 'set'>,
 <class 'set'>,
 <class 'set'>,
 <class 'set'>,
 <class 'set'>,
 <class 'set'>]
```

Comment: Thank you very  very very much Orix.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. :) If you don't mind please accept my answer and mark this question as solved as well